# Data representation suited for UITableViewDataSource

Tags: ios, uitableview

Currently, I have the following set up in my app:

For example, I have a gamelist, where the games have different states and I would like a certain state to be in a certain section etc.

Since I have 3 different states I'll use a NSDictionary with State as key and Array as value and put a certain game with a certain state in the correct array.

Then my code for `numberOfRowsInSection` would be something like:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString* state = [self getStateForSection:section];
    return [[obj objectForKey:state] count];
}
```

The problem is I dislike having the objects in arrays since then I have to look through the whole array whenever I want to access a certain match.

I would instead like to have all matches in a single NSDictionary with matchID as key and NSDictionary with as value (the match).

But how would I do in `UITableView` then?

I could do something where I return allKeys of my NSDictionary but I still have to iterate it to find their current state and add their key to the appropriate list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just also build a `NSDictionary` from `matchID` to `match` on the side as well, simply reusing the same objects and keeping the `NSDictionary` of `NSArray`s just for the table data source. Then the problem is that you have to update both when the data changes. You may also want to look into `NSArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:`

Another possibility is using another data structure known as the [sorted dictionary](https://code.google.com/p/cocoa-sorted-dictionary/wiki/StartHere) which keeps its keys in a specific order. That way you can ask for all the values as an array for the table view and get a constant order, but still be able to do a lookup with a `matchID` directly to a `match`.

Comment: Yeah, well, then Ill still have to go through the array to find a certain match when I need to update it, altough I could find it with filteredArrayUsingPredicate it would probably still search the whole array internally since it isnt sorterd.

Comment: If you place the instance of an object in both the dictionary and the array, there is only one instance, so it does not matter if you change it from the dictionary or the array, the other data structure is updated. What you could do is have each match be associated with an `indexPath` so when a match is updated you can tell the table view to reload that `indexPath`, otherwise you have reload entire sections or the entire table for matches to update on the table. Now you are basically starting to recreate Core Data's `NSFetchedResultsController`

Comment: Oh, you're right, silly me :) didnt think in terms of references :) ill might give this a shot!

Comment: But I still have to find the correct element in the arrays for the data sources since I have to move it from one array to another array!